# while loop and skipping numbers in python

Tags: python, list, count, while-loop

I am making a while loop counter that i want to skip a certain numbers and those number's value+10, +20, +30...and so on. Here's what i have been trying so far:

```
lstLength = 26
skipNum = [2, 8]

lst = []
count = 0
while len(lst) < lstLength:
    count +=1
    if count == skipNum[0] or count == skipNum[1]:
        continue
    lst.append(count)
print(lst)
```

I would like the result list to be lstLength long while skipping numbers 2, 8, 12, 18, 22, 28, 32, 38 and so on....How can i do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
if count % 10 in skipNum:
    continue
```

`%` is the modulus operator, so `count % 10` is the last digit of `count`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt. It will populate your list until it hits a length of 25. It will use the values in `skipNum` to ignore values 2, 8 as well as 2+10, 2+20, ... and 8+10, 8+20, ...

```
lstLength = 26
skipNum = [2, 8]

count = 0
lst = []
while len(lst) < lstLength:
  count += 1

  if count in skipNum:
    continue

  #check if count is equal to 2+10, 2+20, ... or 8+10, 8+20, ... etc. If
  #that's the case, `add` will be `False`

  #map to a list of booleans indicating whether `count = skipNum+(n*10)` for any `n`
  bool_arr = map(lambda x, y: ((count - y) % 10 != 0), skipNum)

  #reduce array of booleans to a single boolean value indicating we can `add`
  add = not any(bool_arr)

  if add:
    lst.append(count)


print(lst)
```

Comment: Sure, I'll try when I get home later.

Comment: @Barmar The docs for `reduce` are here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce. Basically, it applies the `lambda` function to each element in `skipNum`, using the previous result as the `x` parameter (and using the third parameter, `True`, for `x` on the first iteration). So basically, if `(count - y) % 10 == 0` for either element in `skipNum`, the `reduce` call ends up returning `False`, and the item isn't added to the list. This works, but ends up being much slower than your solution.

Comment: I know what `reduce` does, but this is a somewhat unusual use of it, that's why I asked you to add an explanation to the answer.

Comment: @Barmar: I broke the reduce into two operations to make it a little clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Just for comparison's sake, here's a way to implement this using `itertools` functions, which ends up being faster than the `while` loop method:

```
from itertools import count, ifilter, islice

def iter_filt(black_list, lstLen):
    return list(islice(ifilter(lambda x: x % 10 not in black_list, count(1)), lstLen))
```

Usage:

```
>> print(iter_filt([2,8], 26))
[1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 33]
```

The function works by starting with `count(1)`, which will generate an infinite series of numbers starting from 1 (`1,2,3,4,5,6,...`). It then runs that through `ifilter`, which filters out any results where `x % 10 in black_list` (as suggested by Barmar). Then `islice` is used to only take the first `lstLen` results from the `ifiltered` `count` iterator.

Doing it this way is a little faster than the `while` loop approach:

```
from itertools import count, islice, ifilter
import timeit

def while_filt(skipNum, lstLength):
    lst = []
    count_ = 0 
    while len(lst) < lstLength:
        count_ +=1 
        if count_ % 10 in skipNum:
            continue
        lst.append(count_)
    return lst 



def iter_filt(black_list, lstLen):
    return list(islice(ifilter(lambda x: x % 10 not in black_list, count(1)), lstLen))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    black_list = [2,6]
    length = 1000026
    print timeit.timeit("while_filt(%s,%s)" % (black_list, length),
                  setup="from __main__ import while_filt", number=50)
    print timeit.timeit("iter_filt(%s,%s)" % (black_list, length),
                  setup="from __main__ import iter_filt", number=50)
```

Output:

```
dan@dantop2:~$ ./funtimes.py 
15.1266388893  # while_filt
11.8498108387  # iter_filt
```